# How to return an object of a class whose object is parameter inside another struct

Tags: c++

If I have a class structure such as:

```
class Data
{
public:
   Data(int a, int b) : mem_a(a), mem_b(b) {  };
private:
   int mem_a;
   int mem_b;
}

class UseData
{
public:
    UseData() {  };
    Data* returnDataObj(int c) { return DataObj; }
private:
   struct node
   {
      Data dat;
      node* next;
      node(const Data aData) : dat(aData), next(NULL) {  };
   }
   node** table;
}
```

Inside `returnDataObj`, I have somthing that looks like:

```
Data* UseData::returnDataObj(int c)
{
    node* head = table[c];
    if(head == NULL)
       return NULL; //<-- No issues here
    else
       return head;// I get an error on this line - return type does not match;
}
```

That was expected since `head` is of type `node`. Is there a way I can return type `Data` from `returnDataObj` ?

Comment: Surely you mean `return head->dat;`

Comment: Just what is `return DataObj`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You method should be updated to return `&head->dat`, which is of the same type that the method is declared to return.

```
Data* UseData::returnDataObj(int c)
{
    node* head = table[c];

    if(head == NULL)
       return NULL;
    else
       return &head->dat;
}
```

Currently you are trying to return just `head` which is of type `node*`. Clearly you can see the type mismatch.

Comment: Updated. That's a fairly clear error to understand, though. You should spend more time debugging these kinds of issues.